# ActivityIndicator Bounds Graphical Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uiactivityindicatorview

I am using Activity Indicator View in my project. 
I used Constraint with one single storyboard To support all devices.

I want to set UIActivityIndicatorview's Background view as shown in below image which is my ex project's screen.[image: Old Project Activity]

Now I did the same in new project but getting this output as per below screen.
[image: New Project Activity]

Following is my code

```
actiIndicator.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
CGRect frmActi = actiIndicator.bounds;
frmActi.size.width += 20;
frmActi.size.height += 20;
actiIndicator.bounds = frmActi;
```

I want to be the same activity view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Suggest to use https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD for show activity indicator in for your project.

Else i notice that your main activity show process not in main thread during your login process. so you can make your Activity indicatore show on main thread by following code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//here put show code
});
```

Hope that help to you.